# using QProcess->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels) and using QProcess->readall()

Tags: c++, qt

It's my first time to ask question on stackoverflow. And I'm a chinese girl, if my description about this problem has so much grammar error that you can't understand it easyly, I'm so sorry.
Below is my question:
headerfile:

```
class AdbDriver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString PnPutilPath_;
    QProcess *process_;
public:
    explicit AdbDriver(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~AdbDriver();
    void installDriver();
};
AdbDriver::AdbDriver(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){
    PnPutilPath_ = qgetenv("WINDIR") + "\\sysnative\\pnputil.exe";
    process_ = new QProcess();
    process_->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    process_->setStandardOutputFile("E:/log.txt");
}
```

sourcefile:

```
 AdbDriver::~AdbDriver(){
        delete process_;
    }

    void AdbDriver::installDriver(){
        QFile file(PnPutilPath_);
        if(file.exists()){
            qDebug()<<"pnputil.exe exist";    
            QString generaladbDriver = "E:/driver_androidusb/generaladb.inf";
            qDebug()<<"the programming include driver："<<generaladbDriver;
            QFile file(generaladbDriver);
            if(file.exists()){
                qDebug()<<"yes, the driver is right in bihu package";
            }
            else{
                qDebug()<<"loss driver in bihu package";
            }
            QStringList arguments;
            arguments<<"-i"<<"-a"<<generaladbDriver;
            process_->start(PnPutilPath_, arguments);
            while(!process_->waitForStarted()){
                qDebug()<<"wait";
            }
            qDebug()<<"while out";
            process_->waitForReadyRead();
            qDebug()<<"start";
    //      qDebug()<<process_->readAll();
            process_->close();
        }
        else{
            qDebug()<<"sorry, your computer has no tool pnputil.exe.";
        }
    }
```

when i Commented out code

```
qDebug()<<process_->readAll();
```

and use

```
 process_->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
 process_->setStandardOutputFile("E:/log.txt");
```

it works properly.But if i use

```
qDebug()<<process_->readAll();
```

instead of

```
 process_->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
 process_->setStandardOutputFile("E:/log.txt");
```

it will be wrong. what's the reason?

Comment: what's the content of `E:/log.txt`? It that empty?

Answer (score 1):

According to Qt document, both `setReadChannelMode` and `setStandardOutputFile` have to be called before `QProcess::start` to take effect, so replacing

```
qDebug() << process_->readAll();
```

with

```
process_->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
process_->setStandardOutputFile("E:/log.txt");
```

is same as just commenting out `qDebug() << process_->readAll();`.

So I guess the child process does not output anything, so `process_->readAll()` will block, and the program halts.

（你看一下`E:/log.txt`有没有内容，估计是`process_->readAll()`阻塞了）

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't  understand why it is wrong when using "process_->readAll()" and commenting out " process_->setReadChannelMode()  process_->setStandardOutputFile()" .

Comment: And i find that even if i comment out  "process_-> readAll()" and use "process_->setReadChannelMode()" but don't use " process_->setStandardOutputFile()", the program still get wrong.